# Are there differences between EnvDTE or CodeDom when generating Code

Tags: c#, code-generation, codedom, envdte

I have the requirement to generate and read some CS classes with a DSL, I have adopted one method for reading the CS files using EnvDTE and my colleague has used CodeDom to produce the CS files.

Is it just sugar or is there a big difference between...

```
codeClass.AddFunction("DoSomething", vsCMFunction.vsCMFunctionFunction, "bool");
```

and

```
     CodeMemberMethod membMethod = new CodeMemberMethod();
        membMethod.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Static;
        membMethod.ReturnType = new CodeTypeReference("bool");
        membMethod.Name = "DoSomething";
```

I subjectively prefer the EnvDTE but do not know what the 'real' difference is.

Info: C#, Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

Using EnvDTE, I'm not sure you can manipulate AST like you can with CodeDOM. I would go with CodeDOM, or NRefactory from [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) project, which is another open source C# parser/generator.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have not come across the acronym AST before?

Comment: AST stands for Abstract Syntax Tree, which is basically a tree structure that represents the code and allows you to manipulate it in a (more or less) strongly typed way. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree

Answer (score 0):

CodeDOM does not have a way to read source code to produce an AST.  If all you need to do is generate C#, then CodeDOM ships with the .NET framework and so your application would not require Visual Studio to be installed.